# Ignore exceptions printed to stderr in __del__()

Tags: python

According to the [Python (2.7) documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html):

> Due to the precarious circumstances under which __del__() methods are
>   invoked, exceptions that occur during their execution are ignored, and
>   a warning is printed to sys.stderr instead

What would be the most Pythonic way to completely and absolutely ignore an exception raised in __del__() — that is, not only having the exception ignored but also **nothing printed to sterr**. Is there a better way than temporarily redirecting stderr to the null device?

Comment: Your best bet is not to use `__del__` at all.  Ironically, it complicates garbage collection, and is unpredictable when it will be called.  If you can find a way to avoid it, you should.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am assuming this is in a `__del__()` function that you are writing, if so, just catch the exception yourself and ignore it.

```
def __del__(self):
    try:
        # do whatever you need to here
    except Exception:
        pass
```

The logging to stderr only applies for *uncaught* exceptions in `__del__()`.

Comment: Your assumption fails in my case — the `__del__()` is in a library I'm using. Suggestions in this case?

Comment: @Juan You could [monkey patch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) the library, for example if the class was `lib.Cls` then you could do `old_del = lib.Cls.__del__`, `def new_del(self): try: old_del(self) except Exception: pass` `lib.Cls.__del__ = new_del`.  (Obviously this code needs some newlines and indentation).

Comment: @AndrewClark Your terrible medicine helped me a lot! :-) Acknowledged in https://stackoverflow.com/a/77008545/465139

Answer (score 3):

Just use `try`/`except` inside `__del__()`:

```
def __del__(self):
   try:
      # ...
   except:
      pass
```

That'll catch all exceptions and will not print anything.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a try/except block:

```
def __del__(self):
    try:
        something_that_might_throw()
    except:
        pass
```