# How to find __del__ member that ignores exception?

Tags: python, python-2.7, debugging

The case is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977970/ignore-exceptions-printed-to-stderr-in-del), i.e., I get a warning output on stdout:

```
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a
Python object' in 'sage.structure.parent.good_as_coerce_domain' ignored
```

The function `good_as_coerce_domain()` is a `cdef`ed Cython function and the project has no `__del__` member function. The function simply consists of

```
cdef inline bint good_as_coerce_domain(S):
    return isinstance(S,CategoryObject) or isinstance(S,type)
```

and is called dozens if not hundreds of times during startup. Inserting a `print` statement gives me the `S` object but this is not the one with the `__del__`. Rather, it looks like it happens during the `isinstance` call.

Changing the stack depth is no solution. Since the responsible `__del__` is likely in Python itself, I would need either need

- a way to know the type of object whose `__del__` causes the message, or
- a way to turn off the message

but the former would be preferable.

Comment: I must say the way Python handles this is really unsatisfactory. Spamming on stdout is not appreciated. They could have at least an option to switch it off.

Comment: Have you tried making a debug print in front of the return and thusly print out since vital data every time it is called? This should allow you to pinpoint which object caused the error?  Or you could add a try expect around the isinstance call before returning...

Comment: I was wrong, the project though big has not a single `__del__` member function. So the ignoring must come from a library used, probably the python lib itself. Question updated.

Comment: @holroy Indeed I can catch the RuntimeError. I didn't expect this because I thought it was already caught.

Comment: Correction again: there are `__del__` functions I missed, investigating these too.