# _UnixSelectorEventLoop has no attribute _closed (nor other instance attributes) while being deleted in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, tornado

There are a few questions similiar to this but not a duplicate I could find.

I'm doing some automatic unit testing of Python code and running these tests in a Jupyter Notebook. On certain computers (Macs in our computer labs) but not on others (my own Windows machine or some other personal Macs) students see a warning about an ignored error along with their test output. The error boils down to: a `_UnixSelectorEventLoop` object is being deleted, and in its `__del__` method, there's an `if self.is_closed():` test, where `is_closed` is a method that checks the `self._closed` instance variable. For some reason, the `_UnixSelectorEventLoop` object in question does not even have a `_closed` attribute, causing an `AttributeError` which is ignored and printed as a warning due to being raised in the context of deletion.

When I add prints to the `__del__` method I can see this is happening on a `return` line, but enabling `gc` debugging seems to indicate it isn't the result of cyclic garbage collection. My next thought is that a local variable is going out of scope, but I haven't found one via `print(locals())` which is a `_UnixSelectorEventLoop` although maybe I'm not looking hard enough.

In any case, printing `dir(self)` during the `__del__` method shows that NONE of the expected instance variables exist, almost as if this is an instance which never got initialized. When I print the ID of `self` during `__del__` and add a similar print to `__init__`, I see the same number of `__init__` and `__del__` calls (perhaps just a coincidence) but the IDs on `__init__` don't match up. My guess is the object gets copied somewhere in an incomplete way. The `__init__` calls I do see are coming from tornado, but I haven't dealt with that directly before.

Have others come across and solved similar issues with `__del__` on an object getting a hollowed-out object missing instance variables that should be set by `__init__`, particularly in async contexts? Any hints would be appreciated!

Python version is 3.10.

I don't have an MWE right now, although I'll try to find time to cook one up. The fact that it's machine-dependent means I'm not confident in reproducing it, and it only happens in Jupyter Notebook contexts, not running code in normal Python.

I can try to narrow down a bit the parts of my code that trigger it, but I'm worried that the actual trigger is happening via a thread handoff and has nothing to do with the traceback I can print out from within `__del__`.

Comment: FWIW, I observed this error today with Python 3.11 in a Dockerised JupyterLab environment (tagged as "lab-4.0.5", image ID=73d5d57d9321).

Comment: Today I tried "hub-3.1.1", image ID=97dfb7608620), with Tornado 6.2, same error. My use case is slightly different, I use `eval` and `exec` in different execution contexts (try in a temp environment, if result is OK repeat in the global env). Since I deep-copy `globals()` for this, your suspicion about an incomplete copy looks plausible. Unit tests with IPython pass BTW, error happens in Jupyter only.

Answer (score 1):

After wasting 3 days on this issue I can offer a terrible but efficient hack: to monkey-patch the `__del__` method of the `BaseEventLoop` class. This was inspired by [Andrew Clark's comment to this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13977992):

```
import asyncio

# shorthand for the class whose __del__ raises the exception
_BEL = asyncio.base_events.BaseEventLoop

_original_del = _BEL.__del__

def _patched_del(self):
    try:
        # invoke the original method...
        _original_del(self)
    except:
        # ... but ignore any exceptions it might raise
        # NOTE: horrible anti-pattern
        pass

# replace the original __del__ method
_BEL.__del__ = _patched_del
```

I would **love** to file a bug report but I don't know who to contact: the IPython devs, the IPyKernel devs or the Jupyter notebook devs. My use case is somewhat convoluted, currently cannot provide a simple example that triggers the bug.